# table data going outside borders

Tags: html, css, html-table

Briefly , i got

```
<div id="tablewrapper">
<table>
<tr>
<td>veryveryveryveryveryeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryvery longtext</td>
</tr>
<table>
</div>
```

And my very long text is going outside my table,div and wrapper borders. Looking like this

textextexttextextexttextextext(border)|(border)textextexttextextexttextextext

what css rules should i use to displey it in next line like:

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext(border)
                     texttexttexttexttexttexttex

Have tried setting display or width.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **[table-layout: fixed;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** attribute (be sure to give the table a width too, e.g. `100%`) on the `table` along with applying `word-wrap:break-word` to the `td`'s.

[**Here's a jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BUvRm/)

---

**CSS:**

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%
}

td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `word-break:break-all` to break text anywhere:

```
<td style="word-break:break-all">veryveryveryveryveryeryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryvery longtext</td>
```